# Combining multiple integers using *args in functions

Tags: python

I want to create a function combining multiple inputs as integer and use them in my code. Let's say, I have a function like below. How can I concatenate multiple integers (the length/count of them is not defined) without converting them to strings? I tried int(" ".join(args)), but it wants me to enter str, not int.

```
def combine_integers(*args)
   return ....

result = combine_integers(10,20,30,40)
print(result)
```

The output should be 10 20 30 40 (each of them should be called as integer and should be used in a collection if needed).

Comment: store in `list`?

Comment: you could do ```int("".join((str(i) for i in args)))```

Comment: Just do `return args` and `print(*result)`

Comment: int("".join((str(i) for i in args))) worked for me,. Also, I realized that specifying return args and unpacking them (print(*result)) would do the trick, thanks

Comment: Using `int("".join((str(i) for i in args)))` creates ambiguity: if you store `10203040`, then when you come to use it, you can't tell whether it came from the inputs [10, 20, 30, 40] or [1020, 3040] or some other combination.

Comment: I agree with slothrop. It can be hard to analyze stored values.

Answer (score 1):

do you need something like this ? :

```
def combine_integers(lst):
    new_numbers = lst.split(',')
    joined = ''.join(new_numbers)
    print(joined)#output 40201050


input_numbers = input('enter a list of numbers : ')#input 40,20,10,50
sender = combine_integers(input_numbers)
```